# Delete data from two tables by using join condition in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DELETE tbemp.emp_id, 
        tbadd.emp_id 
FROM  TBEMPLOYEE tbemp 
JOIN TBADDRESS tbadd ON (tbemp.emp_id=tbadd.emp_id)
```

Oracle 11g not compile it

Answer (score 1):

This delete statement is not valid in Oracle. There are other statements for deletion, one could be

```
DELETE FROM TBEMPLOYEE tbemp 
WHERE EXISTS (select 'x' 
                from TBADDRESS 
               where tbemp.emp_id=tbadd.emp_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete directly from multiple tables with a join.

But you can enforce a foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
ALTER TABLE tbaddress ADD CONSTRAINT fk_emp FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES tbemployee (emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

DELETE FROM tbemployee; -- This also deletes referencing keys from tbaddress
```